# Como tratar tamanho máximo excedido de upload de arquivos

Tags: java, spring, wildfly

Tenho uma aplicação, que faz o upload de um arquivo (planilhas), porém após um teste recente apontou este erro:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: UT000054: The maximum size 1048576 for an individual file in a multipart request was exceeded
```

já alterei a application.properties para estes valores:

```
multipart.max-file-size=100MB
multipart.max-request-size=100MB
```

porém o erro persiste.
Como posso tratar este erro ?

Comment: Olá! Poderia passar o erro completo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que esteja utilizando Spring Boot para sua aplicação, seguindo a documentação vejo algumas outras propriedades sendo utilizadas:

```
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=200MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=200MB
spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=true
```

[Spring Boot Documentation](https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/) - `Tuning file upload limits`

É possível que também seja necessário alterar a configuração do servidor, conforme apontado por @SeaBiscuit [neste post do StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35748022/multipart-file-maximum-size-exception-spring-boot-embbeded-tomcat).

```
@Bean
public TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory containerFactory() {
    TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory factory = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();
     factory.addConnectorCustomizers(new TomcatConnectorCustomizer() {
        @Override
        public void customize(Connector connector) {
         ((AbstractHttp11Protocol<?>) connector.getProtocolHandler()).setMaxSwallowSize(-1);
        }
     });
     return factory;
}
```

Deve haver alguma configuração em específico para aplicar também no WildFly.

Answer (score -2):

nesse caso você pode mudar na Sua entidade para que o arquivo seja maior
exemplo:@Log -> permite tamanhos maiores no banco
@Lob
byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());